# Regrouping values from a many relationship in Laravel ? (collection of collection)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm beginning with Laravel 5 so my question will probably sound a little silly.
Currently developping a twitter-like feature. A user can post, and can follow some other users so he can see what they are posting.

Let's say I want to display the last 10 posts of the people I follow. So I wrote this :

```
$followed = Auth::user()->follows->load(['posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10);
}]);
```

Now I have a collection of the people I follow, and for each of them, a collection of posts, sorted by creation date... But now, how can I regroup all those posts into a single collection, while keeping the sorting, without an elaborate iteration (if possible) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to do this but I can't think of one. You could try something like:

```
$postsOnly = collect();  # we'll add posts to this and sort it later

foreach ($followed as $person) {

    foreach ($person->posts as $post) {

        $postsOnly->add($post);
    }
}

$postsOnly = $postsOnly->sortBy(function($post) {

    // I don't know if you can sort with a Carbon DateTime object
    // (so convert to a unix timestamp for comparison/sorting)
    return $post->created_at->format('U');        
});
```

You could also try the custom [sort()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_sort) or [sortByDesc()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_sortByDesc) method on a collection depending on your sort requirements.

I haven't tested any of this but hopefully it's mostly right...

Comment: Thank you, that's what I finally did. I also thought there was a simpler way but can't find any !
The sad part is that the sql request which is performed on the Post table by the framework returns exactly what I'm needing...